Why Kishimoto or publishers don't make any spin offs for previous jinchurikis?
I would like to ask why there is no spinoff media(comic, novel, ova, etc) for previous jinchurikis(including the ones that were dead during timeskips).
Boruto was not immediately planned just after the end of Naruto Shippuden, and there are even novel(Shinden and Hiden) for other characters, including some of past characters.
There are a lot of missing stories, that could work well for original audience who was on Naruto for its entire publication, before Boruto was made. I get japanese authors and publishers are totally different from western style publishing of comics and fill in/tie in stories.
But this feels like burying potential of existing characters and pushing all into aliens who lack ideology compared with characters like Maradara.
Is it because of solely on investing everything for Boruto? Or is it just how Japanese authors are?

Some secondary jinchuurikis are already featured prominently in manga and fillers: namely Kushina Uzumaki, Fu of the Waterfall and Blue B. As of why they haven't released an eight-episode special about various Dick Hammerbushes, well, we can't really be in the editor's head. They did release an additional special chapter about Kushina, Minato and how rasengan came to be.

I almost forgot about one shot with Kushina and Minato.
But it's still part of major characters, and trying to bring more readers into Boruto, by doing fanservice for OG fans, imo.
As for Fu and Blue B, it's quite short and more like filler if I am not wrong(restricted/nerfed a lot on their fight scenes, as Fu was stuck with Gaara in trap, and Blue B just result of Edo Tensei. Same for Utakata's filler).
I am more into focusing stories on Yagura's backstory or more info on first generation of Jinchurikis, but yeah it's up to author and the publishers.

And being compatible with bijus and being able to control is quite difficult for jinchurikis in initial setup of Naruto.
It could be quite interesting to see how each came into or failed to control the tailed beasts. Because both Han and Roshi had considerable level of control, during their fight with Akatsuki.
